# Opengl Render Order

Tags: c++, opengl, render

I have an Opengl application which renders a scene model by model.

If, say, I render a model at the front first and then render a model at the back does the model at the back get drawn to the display over the top of the model at the front?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on whether you've enabled *Depth Testing* or not. If Depth Testing is enabled<sup>*</sup>, then the order of how you draw objects has no bearing on the final scene displayed<sup>**</sup>. So as long as in your `setup_gl` or whatever function you use to initialize your scene, before drawing takes place, you've called `glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);`, you don't have to think about the order.

<sup>*</sup> and you haven't changed the *Depth Test Function*, using `glDepthFunc` or some similar function. If you have, (and this is generally only recommended for people who need specialized functionality, so for you, you shouldn't), the depth test will exhibit different behavior.

<sup>**</sup> ... Unless you are using transparent objects, in which case you'll either need to implement an [expensive] order-independent-transparency algorithm in your shader, or draw order **WILL** matter (usually, for transparency, you need to draw back-to-front).

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL handles all commands in exactly the order you issue them. This means that if you draw a front model and then a model in the back, the second model will by default overdraw the first one.

If you want to draw only parts that are actually infront, you have to enable [depth testing](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Depth_Test) (`glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);`). This ensures that only such pixels are written to the backbuffer that are closer to the viewer than what is already stored. Note, that this method only works for non-transparent objects.